# route command displays gateway backward

Tags: centos6, route

Very puzzling problem on CentOS 6. After I issued this command:

```
route add -net 190.160.190.0/24 gw 191.160.203.254
```

I then check with the `route` command, but the gateway IP appears backward:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
190.160.190.0   254.203.160.191 255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 em2
```

Note the gateway is 254.203.160.191 instead of 191.160.203.254. I could actually reproduce the problem on another machine runnign CentOS 6. It happens for only this one rule I'm adding though; similar rules with different IPs apparently work fine.

What could possibly cause this?

Comment: Are those the actual IP addresses you're working with?

Comment: Do you have a directly-attached network into which 191.169.203.254 falls?